# Xcode 8.3.2 : Could not hardlink copy

Tags: ios, simulation

I am getting this error message while trying to launch my app in simulator. What is the actual issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you localized info.plist file..?

Comment: @piyushMathur - Nope

Comment: @PiyushMathur if we do have a localized plist file, is there something else we can try?  We get the same error the 2nd time we run the app on the simulator.  Workflow is... delete app from simulator, run the app, it works, run the app again, it shows that error.

Answer (score 7):

Do below steps,

1. Clean Build
2. Delete Derived Data
3. Simulator (Reset Content and Settings)
4. Quit Xcode 
   & Run Again

Comment: I did the same steps. Now am not getting the issue. May i know the cause for the issue?

Comment: There are many cases for this, like multiple time run app in simulator, some internal process are woking you hit the run etc...

Answer (score 7):

The apps installed in the simulator could have become inconsistent.

Resetting the Content and Settings will solve the issue.

Also try to clear Derived Data then clean and build the project.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the Build number was wrong.
So in the Info.plist the Build number disappeared, it was blank.

To fix this, I had to re-enter the build number.
Delete the app from the simulator
Then when I built the app it installed again on the Simulator and started to work fine in subsequent builds as well.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: This was the only solution that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem is caused by special character in `Product Name`

Note that `Product Name` differs from `Display Name` which is displayed below app icon as your app name.

So don't worry about changing `Product Name` requires change your app name, just choose an ascii name and error gone

[image]

Answer (score -2):

1. Follow the steps to fix the issues.

[Press add to open a window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Flu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LunGf.png)